# Problemas ao exportar app do creator para WWW

Tags: ionic

Galera estou fazendo o layout do meu app pelo creator, e tento exportar as telas para o app que fiz pela linha de comando para o WWW, porém ele executa sempre o projeto da linha de comando(seja blank, tabs ou qualquer outro) e não executa o que eu colei, alguém já passou por isso?

Comment: Não entendi direito.... O que você está digitando?

Answer (score 0):

Temos poucas informações. Partes do código ou do que você está digitando no CLI ajudariam bastante.

De qualquer modo, tente fazer o download do template que está no creator e depois a criação de um novo app com os comandos:

```
ionic start <nome-do-app> <caminho-para-o-folder-local-do-template-baixado>
```

Isso criará um novo app baseado no template q você criou no creator.

Comment: Estou passando pelo mesmo problema que o colega acima, ele executou o comando por exemplo ionic start myApp tabs e fez o import do ionic creator pra dentro da pasta www porém ao executar o ionic serve o template roda o tabs e não o que está dentro do www